# Xilinx SDK (Eclipse) "no matches converting function" Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdk, fpga, xilinx

While trying to compile a .h file inside Xilinx's Eclipse based SDK I got the following error:

***no matches converting function 'MyCallback' to type 'XIicPs_IntrHandler {aka void (*)(void*, long unsigned int)}'***

It points to this line of code:

```
XIicPs_SetStatusHandler (&drv_inst_, &stat_handler_, &MyCallback<void(int)>);
```

Can you explain what's wrong with it ?
The full code and a snapshot of the error message are below:

```
/*
 * I2C_ClientAXI_IIC.h
 *
 *  Created on: May 26, 2016
 *      Author: Elod
 */

#ifndef I2C_CLIENTAXI_IIC_H_
#define I2C_CLIENTAXI_IIC_H_

#include "I2C_Client.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>

#include "xiicps.h"

#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)
#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define LINE_STRING STRINGIZE(__LINE__)

namespace digilent {

// Shim function to extract function object from CallbackRef and call it
// This should call our member function handlers below
template <typename Func>
void MyCallback(void* CallbackRef, int i)
{
  auto pfn = static_cast<std::function<Func>*>(CallbackRef);
  pfn->operator()(i);
}

using namespace std::placeholders;

template <typename IrptCtl>
class PS_IIC: public I2C_Client {
public:

    PS_IIC(uint16_t dev_id, IrptCtl& irpt_ctl, uint32_t irpt_id, uint32_t sclk_rate_Hz) :
        drv_inst_(),
        irpt_ctl_(irpt_ctl),
        stat_handler_(std::bind(&PS_IIC::StatusHandler, this, _1))
    {
        XIicPs_Config* ConfigPtr;
        XStatus Status;

        // Initialize the IIC driver so that it is ready to use.
        ConfigPtr = XIicPs_LookupConfig(dev_id);
        if (ConfigPtr == NULL) {
            throw std::runtime_error(__FILE__ ":" LINE_STRING);
        }

        Status = XIicPs_CfgInitialize(&drv_inst_, ConfigPtr,
            ConfigPtr->BaseAddress);
        if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error(__FILE__ ":" LINE_STRING);
        }

        Status = XIicPs_SelfTest(&drv_inst_);
        if (Status != XST_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(__FILE__ ":" LINE_STRING);
        }

       Status = XIicPs_SetSClk(&drv_inst_, sclk_rate_Hz);
        if (Status != XST_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(__FILE__ ":" LINE_STRING);
        }

        //Register the IIC handler with the interrupt controller
        irpt_ctl_.registerHandler(irpt_id, reinterpret_cast<typename IrptCtl::Handler>(&XIicPs_MasterInterruptHandler), &drv_inst_);
        irpt_ctl_.enableInterrupt(irpt_id);
        irpt_ctl_.enableInterrupts();

        XIicPs_SetStatusHandler (&drv_inst_, &stat_handler_, &MyCallback<void(int)>);
    }

    virtual void read(uint8_t addr, uint8_t* buf, size_t count) override
    {
        // Receive the Data.

        resetFlags();

        XIicPs_MasterRecv(&drv_inst_, buf, count, addr);

        // Wait till all the data is received.
        while (!rx_complete_flag_ && !slave_nack_flag_ && !arb_lost_flag_ && !other_error_flag_) ;

        if (slave_nack_flag_) throw TransmitError("Slave NACK");
        if (arb_lost_flag_) throw TransmitError("Arbitration lost");
        if (other_error_flag_) throw TransmitError("Other I2C error");
    }

    virtual void write(uint8_t addr,  uint8_t const* buf, size_t count) override
    {
        //xintc.h is not const-correct, so we create local copy
        std::vector<uint8_t> buf_local(count);
        buf_local.assign(buf, buf+count);

        resetFlags();

        XIicPs_MasterSend(&drv_inst_, buf_local.data(), buf_local.size(), addr);

        while (!tx_complete_flag_ && !slave_nack_flag_ && !arb_lost_flag_ && !other_error_flag_) ;

        if (slave_nack_flag_) throw TransmitError("Slave NACK");
        if (arb_lost_flag_) throw TransmitError("Arbitration lost");
        if (other_error_flag_) throw TransmitError("Other I2C error");
    }

    virtual ~PS_IIC() { }

private:
    void StatusHandler(int Event)
    {
        if (Event & XIICPS_EVENT_COMPLETE_SEND) //Transmit Complete Event
        {
            tx_complete_flag_ = 1;
        }
        if (Event & XIICPS_EVENT_COMPLETE_RECV)  //Receive Complete Event
        {
            rx_complete_flag_ = 1;
        }
        if (Event & XIICPS_EVENT_NACK)  // Slave did not ACK (had error)
        {
            slave_nack_flag_ = 1;
        }
        if (Event & XIICPS_EVENT_ARB_LOST)      // Arbitration was lost
        {
            arb_lost_flag_ = 1;
        }
        if (Event & (XIICPS_EVENT_TIME_OUT |    //Transfer timed out
                XIICPS_EVENT_ERROR |        // Receive error
                XIICPS_EVENT_SLAVE_RDY))    // Bus transitioned to not busy
        {
            other_error_flag_ = 1;
        }
    }
    void resetFlags()
    {
        tx_complete_flag_ = 0;  // Flag to check completion of Transmission
        rx_complete_flag_ = 0;  // Flag to check completion of Reception
        slave_nack_flag_ = 0;   // Flag to check for NACK error
        arb_lost_flag_ = 0;         // Flag to check for arbitration lost error
        other_error_flag_ = 0;
    }
private:
    XIicPs drv_inst_;
    IrptCtl& irpt_ctl_;
    std::function<void(int)> stat_handler_;
    volatile uint8_t tx_complete_flag_; // Flag to check completion of Transmission
    volatile uint8_t rx_complete_flag_; // Flag to check completion of Reception
    volatile uint8_t slave_nack_flag_;  // Flag to check completion of Reception
    volatile uint8_t arb_lost_flag_;    // Flag to check completion of Reception
    volatile uint8_t other_error_flag_; // Flag to check completion of Transmission
};

} /* namespace digilent */

#endif /* I2C_CLIENTAXI_IIC_H_ */
```

[image]

Comment: `MyCallback` needs two parameters (a pointer and an int), and you're passing only one.

Comment: I see your point - but it's strange.
This file is supplied by the vendor and it compiles well in another version of the project (exact syntax).